# How could I cast to a variable class name?

Tags: c++, casting

I have some classes and a pointer, which class is void*, pointing to one of these classes.

I also have the name of that class in a string variable and I would like to cast that void pointer to that class.

I would like to do something like that:

```
    string className;

    className = "int";

    (className *) voidPointer;
```

is there any way to do that??

thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582331/is-there-a-way-to-instantiate-objects-from-a-string-holding-their-class-name

Comment: What would you possibly do with this?

Comment: C++ is a statically typed language. If you want to do this, you will have to implement your own scheme. The question Joe suggested as a dupe has a few ideas. Voted to close this one.

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible the way you're trying to do.

However, I think [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/any.html) can help you here:

```
boost::any obj;
if (className == "int")
   obj = (int)voidPointer;
else if (className == "short")
   obj = (short)voidPointer;

//from now you can call obj.type() to know the type of value obj holds
//for example
if(obj.type() == typeid(int))
{
    int value = boost::any_cast<int>(obj);
    std::cout <<"Stored value is int = " << value << std::endl;
}
```

That is, use [`boost::any_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost/any_cast.html) to get the value stored in object of [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/any.html) type.

Answer (score 1):

C++ doesn't have reflection so you cannot do this easily.

What you can do is something on these lines

```
string classname;
void * ptr;

if ( classname == "Foo" )
{
    Foo* f = static_cast<Foo*> ( ptr );
}
else if ( classname == "Bar" )
{
    Bar* f = static_cast<Bar*> ( ptr );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do this.  However, you could conceivably use a template class to do this.  Note I am providing a solution, but I don't think you should be storing a `void*` pointer anyway.

```
template<class T>
T* cast(void* ptr) { return static_cast<T*>(ptr); };
```

Then, you can do:

```
int* intPtr = cast<int>(ptr);
```

I repeat, you probably don't need to be using `void*` at all.

Comment: The OP has classnames stored in string.  Your solution doesn't cover it

Comment: I am aware of what was in the OP.  I don't think he should be doing it at all, but unfortunately we only get a snippet of the over-all problem.  Perhaps he wants to cast based on some other "type of" field he has.  Perhaps he wants to store different types in a property-type collection.  You get my drift?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can do that:

```
if (className == "int") {
  int *intPtr = static_cast<int*>(voidPointer);
}
```

This is not very elegant, though - but you can certainly do that if you must (but there is most probably a better solution to your problem).