# Reflective Factory in C++ Derived class unable to access protected methods?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, reflection

Inspired by [answer Johannes Schaub's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/582456/44232) I tried to implement a reflective factory. The idea is that you can create objects by passing the name of the class to a method which creates the concerning object on the heap and returns a pointer to a common base class. Using dynamic_cast and RTTI the objects can be casted back to their original type if necessary. One should be able to use the reflective factory as shown below:

```
// Base is the base class of all objects to create.
class Factory: public AbstractFactory<Base>
{
public:
    Factory()
    {
        m_map["DerivedA"] = &AbstractFactory::createInstance<DerivedA>;
        m_map["DerivedB"] = &AbstractFactory::createInstance<DerivedB>; 
    }
};

int main()
{
    Factory factory;
Base *a = factory.Create("DerivedA");
DerivedA *aa = dynamic_cast<DerivedA*>(a);

    // etc..
}
```

I got this working so far. However there are two main problems I have with the code below. It is ugly and if I make the methods of the abstract factory protected it complaints that it cannot access the `createInstance()` method. This is something I do not understand. By definition the derived class should be able to access the protected methods of the base class. I tested the code in VS 2008. Further notes: I know the base class is not really abstract, because it does not contain a pure virtual function. I know about std::function however so far I haven't used it. Maybe I'll do in the future.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <string>

struct Base
{
    virtual std::string SayHello() = 0;
};

struct DerivedA: public Base
{

    virtual std::string SayHello() 
    {
        return "Hello from DerivedA";
    }

};

struct DerivedB: public Base
{

    virtual std::string SayHello() 
    {
        return "Hello form DerivedB";
    }

};

/**
 * @brief Reflective Factory class. Creates objects of classes which derive from
 *        a common base class.
 *
 */
template<class BASE_T>
struct AbstractFactory
{

// Macro to call ptrs to member functions as recommended in the C++ FAQ lite.
// http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html
#define CALL_MEMBER_FN(object, ptrToMember) ((object).*(ptrToMember))

    // Recall funcion ptr syntax for members: ReturnType (class::*) (Arguments)

    // using a typedef makes it easier..
    typedef BASE_T*  (AbstractFactory::*func_ptr_type) ();
    // retType^ ClassName^ AliasName^  Arguments^

    typedef std::map<std::string, func_ptr_type> map_type;

    template<typename DERIVED_T> 
    BASE_T * createInstance() 
    { return new DERIVED_T; }

    map_type m_map;

    /**
     * @brief Creates an object from a class with the name given as string.             
     */
    BASE_T * Create(std::string className)
    {
        // Note the last () at the end.
        return CALL_MEMBER_FN(*this, m_map[className])();
    }

#undef CALL_MEMBER_FN

};

class Factory: public AbstractFactory<Base>
{

public:

    Factory()
    {
        m_map["DerivedA"] = &AbstractFactory::createInstance<DerivedA>;
        m_map["DerivedB"] = &AbstractFactory::createInstance<DerivedB>; 
    }

};

int main()
{
    Factory factory;

    Base *a = factory.Create("DerivedA");

    DerivedA *aa = dynamic_cast<DerivedA*>(a);

    std::cout << typeid(a).name()  << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(*a).name()  << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(aa).name() << std::endl;

    std::cout << aa->SayHello() << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

**Update**

The exact error I get using VS 2008 is (in German, sorry was not my choice..)

```
1>------ Erstellen gestartet: Projekt: ReflectiveFactory, Konfiguration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Kompilieren...
1>main.cpp
1>.\main.cpp(82) : error C2248: "AbstractFactory<BASE_T>::createInstance": Kein Zugriff auf protected Member, dessen Deklaration in der AbstractFactory<BASE_T>-Klasse erfolgte.
1>        with
1>        [
1>            BASE_T=Base
1>        ]
1>        .\main.cpp(55): Siehe Deklaration von 'AbstractFactory<BASE_T>::createInstance'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            BASE_T=Base
1>        ]
1>.\main.cpp(83) : error C2248: "AbstractFactory<BASE_T>::createInstance": Kein Zugriff auf protected Member, dessen Deklaration in der AbstractFactory<BASE_T>-Klasse erfolgte.
1>        with
1>        [
1>            BASE_T=Base
1>        ]
1>        .\main.cpp(55): Siehe Deklaration von 'AbstractFactory<BASE_T>::createInstance'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            BASE_T=Base
1>        ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Create` method must be accessible to end users, which means that either that method is `public` in `AbstractFactory` or it is moved to `Factory` and made public there. The rest of the code in `AbstractFactory` can be protected.

It seems that only gcc accepts the code (clang++, comeau reject it) and it could be rightfully rejected (I would have to look into the standard). At any rate a simple workaround would be to create a helper function that will provide the member function pointer for you:

```
template <typename B>
template <typename D>
AbstractFactory<B>::func_ptr_type AbstractFactory<B>::getCreateInstancePtr() const {
   return &AbstractFactory<B>::createInstance<D>;
}
```

This template member method of the `AbstractFactory` template can be protected, as you are directly calling it on your own base in the actual `Factory`:

```
Factory::Factory() {
        m_map["DerivedA"] = getCreateInstancePtr<DerivedA>();
        m_map["DerivedB"] = getCreateInstancePtr<DerivedB>();
}
```

---

After checking with the standard:

11.5p1 [class.protected]

> Except when forming a pointer to member (5.3.1), the access must be through a
>   pointer to, reference to, or object of the derived class itself (or any class derived from that class) (5.2.5). **If the access is to form a pointer to member, the nested-name-specifier shall name the derived class (or any class derived from that class)**.

That is, the expression `m_map["DerivedA"] = &AbstractFactory::createInstance<DerivedA>;` is incorrect, while `m_map["DerivedA"] = &Factory::createInstance<DerivedA>;` is correct (regarding access specifiers, but not types, the left hand side is an `B* (AbstractFactory<B>::*)( std::string )` and the right hand side is a `B* (Factory::*)( std::string )`, so the assignment would fail.

This plays nice with the semantics of `protected` everywhere else, and in particular with not being able to access the protected members of other than your own base subobject:

```
class base {
protected:
   int x;
};
struct derived : base {
   static void f( base& b ) {
      b.x = 5;                 // Error: cannot access base::x from this context
   }
};
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. At first I had exactly that, all methods protected except Create() public. However I got this error with VS 2008: error C2248: "AbstractFactory<BASE_T>::createInstance" No access to member, etc

Comment: @Nils: The code should compile, this might be an issue with the compiler. Try creating a different equivalent test case where the base is not a template (i.e. manually create the equivalent of `AbstractFactory<Base>`) and see if the compiler still complains.

Comment: yeah I think so.. will try at home with llvm and clang

Comment: @Nils: g++ 4.5 accepts the code, clang++ 3.0 and comeau rejects it with the similar error message... It makes some kind of sense (in the same sense that you cannot call a protected method on a reference to a base other than yourself (i.e. `protected` grants you access to your own `base`)

Comment: Maybe those compilers try to close a loophole in the protected member mechanism that allows everyone to access protected members with the following legal C++03 code: #define ACCESS(A, M, N) struct N : get_a1<void A>::type { using get_a1<void A>::type::M; } \ template<typename T> struct get_a1; template<typename R, typename A1> struct get_a1<R(A1)> { typedef A1 type; }; ACCESS((stack<int>), c, get_c); int main() { stack<int> p; p.push(10); p.push(11); cout << (p.*&get_c::c).front(); }

Comment: @PlasmaHH: The question is whether that code is actually legal in C++03 or not. That is, whether taking the address of the function is closer to *calling* the function on your base subobject or calling the function on a reference to a base that is not your own subobject. (and btw, there are ways of accessing all private and protected members legally in C++03 through the use of explicit template instantiation that do not involve inheritance...)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: A comment here is probably too few space to prove that the above code is legal, but about 3 years ago we had a lengthy discussion in ##C++ of freenode and came to the conclusion that indeed this is legal and an unfortunate loophole (well, some people think this is the intended behaviour of protected)

Comment: @PlasmaHH: While the code that you present seems to be valid in C++03 (I have not been able to disprove it looking at the standard, but I am not fully convinced either) I don't think that it is related to the question. In your code, the derived type is bringing the base protected member into a public scope, and then obtaining the address of a public function, while in the question it is trying to obtain the address of a protected function in the base class.