# what is Base*(*)()

Tags: c++, templates, stl

Can someone please explain the **Base*(*)()** for me as in:

`typedef std::map<std::string, Base*(*)()> map_type;`

And how would one return it from a function?

I presume it is a function pointer, a Base* is returned, but what is this (*).

I found this in the following SO post [Is there a way to instantiate objects from a string holding their class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582331/is-there-a-way-to-instantiate-objects-from-a-string-holding-their-class-name)

Thanks

Comment: [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/) says `Base*(*)()` is a syntax error, interesting.

Comment: @FredOverflow: I think we have to assume that `Base` is defined as a type.

Comment: @FredOverflow: Base an abstract base class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Base* (*)()` is a type: pointer to function returning `Base*`. The `*` means that it is a pointer and the `()` are used to to override the precedence to ensure that the pointer applies to the function itself and not the return type.

You can return it from a function by returning the name of a function of the appropriate type.

E.g.

```
Base* f();

Base* (*g())()
{
    return f;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's the type of a function pointer of a function of signature `Base*()`:

```
Base * foo();

Base * (*fp)() = &foo;
```

Or in your case:

```
map_type callbacks;
callbacks["Foo"] = &foo;
```

To invoke:

```
Base * p = callbacks["Foo"]();  // same as "p = foo();"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately I can't up-vote your answer due to a lack of points.