# specifying an object type at runtime

Tags: c++, rtti

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to instantiate objects from a string holding their class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582331/is-there-a-way-to-instantiate-objects-from-a-string-holding-their-class-name)

I've written a Vbo template class to work with vertex buffer objects in opengl.  I'm writing for multiple platforms in c++.

I'd like to set the type from a config file at runtime.

e.g.

```
<vbo type="bump_vt" ... />

Vbo* pVbo = new Vbo<bump_vt>(...);
```

Is there some way I can do this without a large if else block e.g.

```
 Vbo* pVbo;

if( sType.compareTo("bump_vt") == 0 )
    pVbo = new Vbo<bump_vt>(...);
else if
    ...
```

thanks

Comment: See the factory design pattern

Answer (score 2):

C++ doesn't allow that, because types are resolved during compilation.

But you may use std::map to simplify the process.