# NSClassFromString equivalent for BlackBerry-10

Tags: c++, ios, blackberry-10

Does [NSClassFromString](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/NSClassFromString) from iOS have an equivalent in the BlackBerry 10 SDK?

Comment: C++ is not a language that uses a runtime, so it has no equivalent.

Comment: There are very few cases when you really need this method. Probably you should redesign the app to avoid this method at all.

Comment: Voting to reopen - Just because the answer is 'no' doesn't make this less of a question.

Comment: There is a *yes* answer. See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is an equivalent to `NSClassFromString` provided you use the Qt meta type system.

You'll need to use to `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` macro and `qRegisterMetaType`:

```
class UserClass : public Superclass {
    ...
}

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(UserClass)


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    qRegisterMetaType<UserClass>("UserClass");

    ....
}
```

Then you can create an instance of your class with the following code:

```
int id = QMetaType::type("UserClass");
UserClass *instance = (UserClass*)(QMetaType::construct(id));
```

I guess this approach to create objects is used by QML as well, e.g. in the *attachedObjects* section.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this natively in C++, C++ is a fairly static language that does not have the runtime capabilities that Objective-C has. It is possible, with a bit of hard graft, if you map all your Class names with instances, using the template mechanism. This is described in "[Is there a way to instantiate objects from a string holding their class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582331/is-there-a-way-to-instantiate-objects-from-a-string-holding-their-class-name) ".

As for the BB10 SDK, based on the assumption that it's Java, this **is** possible.

```
Class myClassName = Class.forName("ClassName");
ClassName myInstance = myClassName.newInstance();
```

**Update:** BB10 SDK is C++, as such there isn't a native way to do this, except what is mentioned above.

Comment: BB10 is actually C++ based. It can run Android applications but its native language is C++.