# c++ factory pattern syntax

Tags: c++, factory-pattern

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582331/is-there-a-way-to-instantiate-objects-from-a-string-holding-their-class-name), the accepted answer uses the following syntax:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, Base*(*)()> map_type;
```

Can someone explain what the (*) means, I've never seen it before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a [function pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer) that returns a `Base` pointer and takes no arguments, e.g.

```
struct Base {};

Base* myfun() {
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    std::map<std::string, Base*(*)()> mymap;
    mymap.insert(std::make_pair("hello", myfun));
}
```

<kbd>[Example](http://ideone.com/5semL9)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks.  I get that the return type is a Base*, what exactly is the (*) meant to signify?

Comment: @stackuser It's a function pointer without a name. Take a look at the linked wiki page.

Comment: @stackuser That it is a pointer, a function pointer to be precise. The parenthesis are part of the syntax for specifying a function pointer. There's no name as Jiri hinted since it is not needed.

Comment: can we add a name, for readability?
std::map<std::string, Base*(*function)()> mymap;

Comment: @vincentB not in this case since it's a template argument