# Is there any way to get actual type from a string value?

Tags: c, java-native-interface

I'm learning the C programming language.

Is there any good/reasonable way to get the actual type from a string value?

I already heard the `sizeof` operator is *almost* a compile-time thing.

Say we have the following string literal which may be provided in runtime.

```c
char *name_of_long_long_int = "long long int";
```

Is there any way to do something effects following?

```c
size_t size_of_long_long_int = sizeof(long long int);
```

Comment: What do you mean by `way to get the actual type from a string value` ? In C strings are represented as set of characters which should be of type `char ` Like `char *` or `char a[]` .. In order calculate the length you can use `strlen()`

Comment: @Gopi Sorry for the confusion. I actually want to know if C has anything like [Class.forName(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName-java.lang.String-)

Comment: @JinKwon, No, there isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not built-in function that can do such mapping.

But you can do this yourself using if-else or switch structure that is limited to your application.

There is one library called "typedef.h" //It is available in C++, I don't know about C

It has some functions like type.id() which can do reverse mapping, may be you can find a way in that lib.

//Only for C++ not for C as you requested but still you might get some idea :

You can also do this with dictionary using map

Here's very helpful link for that :
[Is there a way to instantiate objects from a string holding their class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582331/is-there-a-way-to-instantiate-objects-from-a-string-holding-their-class-name)