# Automatically build a map from strings to templated factory function

Tags: c++, templates, factory, instantiation, command-line-arguments

I would like to be able to instantiate a set of *templated* C++ objects based on selected command line parameters. The solution below (suggested by [Is there a way to instantiate objects from a string holding their class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582331/is-there-a-way-to-instantiate-objects-from-a-string-holding-their-class-name) ) would work if the types to be instantiated (i.e., the `Character` classes) were not templated.

Also important: the code below allows each subclass of `Character` to register itself.  This means that users can add additional subclasses of `Character` without having to touch any of the code in the library or explicitly manage a list of all possible subtypes.  **Question:** Is there a way to get this same functionality for templated classes?

Users of the library choose the value of the template parameter when parsing the command line in `main`.  This means that `CharacterDescription::make` and, as a result, the `CharacterDescription` class must also be templated. At this point, I can't figure out how to let each `Character` subclass "register" itself without maintaining a central list of all possible subclasses.  The templated version of `makeCharacters` below almost does what I want --- I just want to set up the code so that `makeCharacters` does not maintain a list of all the subclasses.

(I suspect the answer will require some #define magic; but, I'm not seeing how to do it.)

---

Character.hpp

```
// Base Class
class Character {

};

// Descriptor for subclasses that may be instantiated.
// (i.e., contains the parameters used for the option parser 
// as well as a pointer to a factory function)
class CharacterDescription {

  typedef Character* (*CharacterFactory)(const char* params);

public:
  const char* optionName;
  const CharacterFactory factory;

    CharacterDescription(const char* pOpt, const CharacterFactory pFactory) :
        optionName(pOpt), factory(pFactory) {
      characterList.push_back(*this);
    }

  template<typename T>
  static Character *make(const char *params) {
    return new T(params);
  }

  static vector<CharacterDescription> characterList;

};
```

Character.cpp

```
vector<CharacterDescription>  CharacterDescription::characterList;
```

Animal.hpp

```
// Example subclass that may be requested on the command line.
class Animal : public Character {

public:
  Animal(const char* /*params*/) {}

public:
  static CharacterDescription description;
};
```

Animal.cpp

```
CharacterDescription Animal::description("animal", CharacterDescription::make<Animal>);
```

main.cpp

```
    // Yes, this is gross, but it gets the point across
    vector<Character*> makeCharacters(int argc, const char* argv[]){

      vector<Character*> characters;
      for (int i = 1;i < argc; i++) {
        const char* current = argv[i];
    auto foundItem = std::find_if(CharacterDescription::characterList.begin(),
    CharacterDescription::characterList.end(),
    [current](const CharacterDescription& item) {return strcmp(item.optionName,current)==0;});
    if (foundItem != CharacterDescription::characterList.end() ) {
      characters.push_back((*foundItem).factory(argv[i+1]));
    }
  }
  return characters;
}
```

templated version of `makeCharacters`

```
template<typename T>
vector<Character<T>*> makeCharacters(int argc, const char* argv[]){

  vector<CharacterDescription<T>> characterList;

  //
  // **Key question:**  Is there a way to distribute these lines of code 
  // to the .hpp or .cpp file for each subclass?
  //
  characterList.push_back({"animal", CharacterDescription<T>::template make<Animal<T>>});
  characterList.push_back({"tree", CharacterDescription<T>::template make<Tree<T>>});
  characterList.push_back({"rock", CharacterDescription<T>::template make<Rock<T>>});

  vector<Character<T>*> characters;
  for (int i = 1;i < argc; i++) {
    const char* current = argv[i];
    auto foundItem = std::find_if(characterList.begin(),
                                  characterList.end(),
                                  [current](const CharacterDescription<T>& item) {return strcmp
                                                                                           (item.optionName,current)==0;});
    if (foundItem != characterList.end() ) {
      characters.push_back((*foundItem).factory(argv[i+1]));
    }
  }
  return characters;
}
```

Comment: You already have a static `CharacterDescription` in all of the derived classes, don't you? Each of those constructors registers themselves to the `CharacterDescription::characterList`.

Comment: Yes, but that's for the non-templated version.  When you make the Character and CharacterDescrption class templated, you can't add CharacterDescription<T> to the derived class, because you don't know what T is.