# How to get an object of a unknown class with given classname

Tags: c++, c++11, function-templates

I am searching for a way to determine at runtime, which type of object should be alloced (based on a given class name, which is of type `const char*`).

Well the simplest way of course is to use loads of `if`s /`else if`s, but that doesnt seem applicable, because i have > 100 different classes(well at least they all derive from one base class), and i have to add new classes quite regularly aswell.

I already came up with a first draft, but sadly it doesnt compile yet (mingw & g++ 4.4)

```
template<typename TBase, typename TDerived, typename... TArgs>
Base* get_classobject(const char* classname)
{
    if(strcmp(classname,typeid(TDerived).name())==0)
        return new TDerived; //
    else if(sizeof...(TArgs)>0)
        return get_classobject<TBase,TArgs...>(classname);
    else
        return 0;
}


int main()
{
    Base* obj = get_classobject<Base,A,Foo,B,C>("Foo");
    // ^- Types A B C and Foo are all derived from Base
    delete obj; //of course we got an virtual dtor ;)
    return 0;
}
```

but that `sizeof...(TArgs)>0` doesnt stop gcc from trying to generate code for `get_classobject<TBase,const char*>(const char*)` which fails

Do you have any idea, how to fix this, or any other idea ?
Thanks.

EDIT: i solved it:

```
template<typename TBase, typename TDerived>
Base* get_classobject(const char* classname)
{
    if(strcmp(classname,typeid(TDerived).name())==0)
        return new TDerived;
    return 0;
}

template<typename TBase, typename TDerived, typename TArg, typename... TArgs>
Base* get_classobject(const char* classname)
{
    if(strcmp(classname,typeid(TDerived).name())==0)
        return new TDerived;
    return get_classobject<TBase,TArg,TArgs...>(classname);
}
```

EDIT For interested readers:
You should now that the implementation above is NOT compiler independent at all.
The output of `typeif(sometype).name()` is compiler/implementation specific.
Using a `static const char* name` variable or function inside all Derived classes, would fix this, but adds a bunch of work(of course you can use a macro for this, but if you are using macros already, you could aswell use another object factory method)

Comment: Smells like you need to implement a factory and `clone` methods.  Using a `clone()` interface, you can create objects of a family and not need to know their class name.

Comment: I don't want to seem critical, but really... this smells bad. First of all the use of `typeid` is quite controversial, but I would also like to point out the inefficiency of such a method > you perform a search with linear complexity and you have to actually precise ALL the possible types that could get generated... and I don't even want to think about the nightmarish maintenance cost.

Comment: typeid can be easily substituted with a static ::name function, linear search is not an issure since i only call this method once (besides that any other object factory ive looked at also has a linear search or abuses macros)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just declare

```
template<typename TBase, typename TDerived, typename TArg, typename... TArgs>
```

?

Then you can specialize for the case of

```
typename TBase, typename TDerived, typename TArg
```

Comment: wouldnt it even fail one recursion step earlier if i do that ?

Comment: You're trying to get 1+ template parameters, instead of 0+ right? You can specialize the template for the 0 case.

Answer (score 2):

Read the answers over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582331/c-is-there-a-way-to-instantiate-objects-from-a-string-holdig-their-class-name), you likely need a factory.

Answer (score 1):

How about making a specialized get_classobject() with no variadic temlates? That would stop the recursion.

You would then have one definition with variadic template, and another one of just `template<typename TBase, typename TDerived>`. Another idea is to make a non-template overload that accepts just const char*, and returns 0.

Comment: Already tried that, still got
`error: no matching function for call to 'get_classobject(const char*&)'|`

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you are looking for the classical object factory pattern. Have a look at this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410823/factory-method-implementation-c). Personally I like this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410823/factory-method-implementation-c/534396#534396)

Comment: when using that pattern you have to write the code yourself, using my way the compiler generates it for me ;)

Comment: @smerlin If I understand *your* way you will need to chain/write all derived classes every time you need to call `get_classobject()`. So when adding a class or removing one this is an administrative/manual process. The way I describe is a little more *automatic*. Basically you only need to add two lines. METADECL in the class declaration and METAIMPL in a compile-unit (.cpp file), preferably close to a constructor. This automated feature of this solution is what really appeals to me, one can then even add classes in runtime by loading shared objects (.so/.dll files) Done that...

Comment: i only have to call this function once anyway, and if i had to call them more than once, i would add an (inline) wrapper function, so that i only have to write the classes once